# Function composition and inverse

Tags: functions, inverse, function-and-relation-composition

Consider *f* : ℝ \ {1} → ℝ \ {1} given by *f(x)* = x/(x-1)

I need to find:

1) *f* ◦ *f* ◦ *f* and

2) the inverse function *f^-1(x)*

So far I have:

1) *f(f(x/(x-1))* = *f(x)* = *x/(x-1)* which is suspicious to me so I was wondering if I messed that up.

2) If I understand correctly, the inverse will be *x=y/(y-1)* solved for *y*?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that the inverse can be found by solving for $y$ as you wrote.

But your answer to part 1 suggests that $f^2$ composed with $f(x)$, gives the identity function $g(x) = x$. That suggests an easy way to identify $f^{-1}$.